# Update an existing node concatenating the ID(deeper level) before that value in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

i'm trying with XSLT to update an existing node (ItemDescription) with the concatenation of InternalID(in deeper level) and the existing description.

Origin XML

```
<urn:ExternalReqForApprovalImportRequest xmlns:urn="urn:Ariba:Buyer:vrealm_1" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" partition="" variant="">
    <urn:ExternalReqForApprovalInput_Item>
        <urn:item>
            <urn:Name>Line 1</urn:Name>
            <urn:Operation>NEW</urn:Operation>
            <urn:ExternalReqLineItems>
                <urn:item>
                    <urn:ExternalLineNumber>2</urn:ExternalLineNumber>
                    <urn:ItemDescription>TEST DESCRIPTION 1</urn:ItemDescription>
                    <urn:Quantity>1.00</urn:Quantity>
                    <urn:LineExtrinsics>
                        <Extrinsics>
                            <Extrinsic name="InternalID">7000083</Extrinsic>
                        </Extrinsics>
                    </urn:LineExtrinsics>
                </urn:item>
            </urn:ExternalReqLineItems>
        </urn:item>
        <urn:item>
            <urn:Name>Line 2</urn:Name>
            <urn:Operation>NEW</urn:Operation>
            <urn:ExternalReqLineItems>
                <urn:item>
                    <urn:ExternalLineNumber>2</urn:ExternalLineNumber>
                    <urn:ItemDescription>TEST DESCRIPTION 2</urn:ItemDescription>
                    <urn:Quantity>1.00</urn:Quantity>
                    <urn:LineExtrinsics>
                        <Extrinsics>
                            <Extrinsic name="InternalID">7000084</Extrinsic>
                        </Extrinsics>
                    </urn:LineExtrinsics>
                </urn:item>
            </urn:ExternalReqLineItems>
        </urn:item>     
    </urn:ExternalReqForApprovalInput_Item>
</urn:ExternalReqForApprovalImportRequest>
```

The result should be something like this:

```
<urn:ExternalReqForApprovalImportRequest xmlns:urn="urn:Ariba:Buyer:vrealm_1" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" partition="" variant="">
    <urn:ExternalReqForApprovalInput_Item>
        <urn:item>
            <urn:Name>Line 1</urn:Name>
            <urn:Operation>NEW</urn:Operation>
            <urn:ExternalReqLineItems>
                <urn:item>
                    <urn:ExternalLineNumber>2</urn:ExternalLineNumber>
                    <urn:ItemDescription>7000083|TEST DESCRIPTION 1</urn:ItemDescription>
                    <urn:Quantity>1.00</urn:Quantity>
                    <urn:LineExtrinsics>
                    </urn:LineExtrinsics>
                </urn:item>
            </urn:ExternalReqLineItems>
        </urn:item>
        <urn:item>
            <urn:Name>Line 2</urn:Name>
            <urn:Operation>NEW</urn:Operation>
            <urn:ExternalReqLineItems>
                <urn:item>
                    <urn:ExternalLineNumber>2</urn:ExternalLineNumber>
                    <urn:ItemDescription>7000084|TEST DESCRIPTION 2</urn:ItemDescription>
                    <urn:Quantity>1.00</urn:Quantity>
                    <urn:LineExtrinsics>
                    </urn:LineExtrinsics>
                </urn:item>
            </urn:ExternalReqLineItems>
        </urn:item>     
    </urn:ExternalReqForApprovalInput_Item>
</urn:ExternalReqForApprovalImportRequest>
```

Im using the XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:p1="urn:Ariba:Buyer:vrealm_1">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I'm missing how to go to ItemDescription and concatenate the values, what should be the way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a template for each element you want to modify:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:urn="urn:Ariba:Buyer:vrealm_1">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="urn:ItemDescription">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="../urn:LineExtrinsics/Extrinsics/Extrinsic[@name='InternalID']"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="urn:LineExtrinsics">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```